# Minimum distance of binary bch codes

Tags: coding-theory

I have to prove that, given a narrow-sense binary bch code, its minimum distance (i.e. Hamming distance) is always odd.

Any idea/hint on how to start the proof?

Edit: I write down the definitions we use:

**Definition ((primitive) BCH codes)** Let $\mathbb{F}$ be the splitting field of $x^n-1$ on $\mathbb{F}_q$ and let $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ be a primitive $n$-root of unity. Let $S=\{m, m+1, \ldots, m+\delta -2\}$ be such that
$$0\le m \le \ldots \le m+\delta -2\le n-1.$$
If $C$ is the $[n,k,d]_q$ cyclic code with defining set $S$, we say that $C$ is a *(primitive) BCH code* of defining distance $\delta$.

**Definition (binary narrow-sense BCH code)** For any positive integer $a$ and $d_0\le 2^a-2$ we can consider a (primitive) BCH code $C$ with parameters 
$$q=2 \qquad n=2^a-1 \qquad m=1 \qquad \delta =d_0.$$
We say that $C$ is the *binary narrow-sense (primitive) BCH code* of length $2^a-1$ and designed distance $\delta$.

Comment: What is your _definition_ of a narrow-sense binary BCH code?

Comment: I have added the definitions to the question

Comment: I'm fairly sure it can be done as follows. Think of the extended code. Its minimum distance is obviously even (all the words have even weight). In the narrow sense case the extended code has a transitive automorphism group. This implies that there exists minimal weight words with $1$ in the extended position. Therefore the minimum weight of the unextended code is odd.

Comment: @Bobech Do you how to use that as a hint?